# Sumar elementos repetidos de una ArrayList personalizado en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un problema al sumar los valores duplicados existentes en un arraylist. Tengo una clase llamada ProductosOBJ con la siguiente estructura:

```
public class ProductosObj{
private String code, nombre;
private int cant;
public ProductosObj() {
}

public ProductosObj(int id, String code, String nombre, int cant) {
    this.code = code;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cant = cant;
}

   public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public int getCant() {
    return cant;
}

public void setCant(int cant) {
    this.cant = cant;
}
}
```

Bueno, en otra clase, el usuario es capaz de agrega los productos a una lista, y tras presionar un boton el programa debe tomar esta lista y sumar los elementos repetidos y para ello utilizo la siguiente función:

```
ArrayList<ProductosOBJS> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<product.size();i++){
        for(int j =0; j<product.size(); j++){
            if(product.get(i).getCode().equals(product.get(j).getCode())){
                if(!lista.contains(product.get(i))){
                    int cant = product.get(i).getCant() + 1;
                    product.get(i).setCant(cant);
                }
            }
            lista.add(product.get(i));
        }
    }

for(int i =0; i<lista.size(); i++){
        Log.d("lista", lista.get(i).getCode()+" "+lista.get(i).getCant());
    }
```

Al probar la app, ingreso 4 elementos iguales, pero al presionar el botón genera 2 elementos distintos en la lista a pesar de que los códigos son exactamente iguales

```
D/lista: 7802264000054 2
D/lista: 7802264000054 2
```

¿En que me he equivocado?. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece el doble bucle, para recorrer la lista `product`, además la condición: `if(!lista.contains(product.get(i)))` podría no dar el resultado esperado. La condición pregunta si existe la instancia de ese producto en la lista, pero en la clase `ProductosObj` no has implementado los [métodos `equals()` ni `hashCode()`](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/entiendo-los-metodos-de-java-equals-y-hashcode/) por lo que Java devolverá true si existe exactamente la instancia en cuestión, no si ya existe otra instancia con el mismo "code".

Te propongo otro algoritmo algo más eficiente para conseguir el resultado esperado usando un ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ProductosOBJS> lista = new ArrayList<>();

for(ProductosOBJS oneProduct: product){
  Optional<ProductosOBJS> productInLista = lista.stream().filter(p -> p.getCode().equals(oneProduct.getCode())).findAny();
  if (productInLista.isEmpty()) {
    lista.add(oneProduct);
  } else {
    ProductosOBJS existingProduct = productInLista.get();
    existingProduct.setCant(existingProduct.getCant() + 1);
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, existe otra solución, no basada en `ArrayList`, que sería más eficiente y en mi opinión más adecuada para este tipo de escenarios, se trata de calcular los contadores en una estructura independiente, en concreto un `Map` donde se accede por código de producto:

```
Map<String, Integer> contadores = new HashMap<>();

for(ProductosOBJS oneProduct: product){
  Integer contador = contadores.get(oneProduct.getCode());
  contadores.put(oneProduct.getCode(), contador == null ? 1 : ++contador);
}

for(String productCode: contadores.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("productCode: " + productCode+", cantidad: "+contadores.get(productCode));
}
```